# Getting tweets from a specific period of time based on a keyword using python code

Tags: api, twitter

can anyone share code to ge tweets from a certain period of time from using twitter api 1.1 from a certain duration of time.(say all the tweets with keyword "iphone" from 2015 march  to 2015 december)

Answer (score 0):

No.

Because Twitter does not allow search this far back on their API.

If you had used the search function:

- [How can I get tweets older than a week (using tweepy or other python libraries)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24214189/how-can-i-get-tweets-older-than-a-week-using-tweepy-or-other-python-libraries)
- [Twitter API not showing old tweets?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14192155/twitter-api-not-showing-old-tweets)
- [Tweepy: get old tweets now possible with Twitter search api?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28267640/tweepy-get-old-tweets-now-possible-with-twitter-search-api)

Also, asking for "give me the code to do x" questions are off-topic here. (For Twitter tutorials, see the Twitter API documentation, or use a search engine)